# How to fill matrix in a class method?

Tags: c#, arrays, class, methods

I created a class `Matrix`. I have created a method of filling the matrix and I have an error. What is the problem?

```
class Matrix
{
    private static int n, m;
    private string[,] arr = new string[n, m];
    public int N
    {
        set 
        {
            n = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return n;
        }
    }
    public int M
    {
        set
        {
            m = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return m;
        }
    }

    public string[,] SetMatrix()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                arr[i, j] = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    Console.WriteLine("- enter n");
    matrix.N = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("- enter m");
    matrix.M = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    string[,] arr= new string[matrix.N, matrix.M];
    Console.WriteLine("enter matrix data");

    arr = matrix.SetMatrix(); //Error at this line

    Console.ReadKey();    
}
```

Error:
`An unhandled exception of type "System.IndexOutOfRangeException" in Matrix.exe`

For more information: `Index was outside the bounds of the array.`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what error? ehat is `spreadSheet` variable?

Comment: So error is thrown in method `SetTable`, but you showed us method `SetMatrix`. Care to show the real method? Also what is the error you are getting?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type "System.IndexOutOfRangeException" in SpreadsheetSimulator.exe

For more information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: @ВладимирНагорный, this should be part of the question, not a comment. How do you initialize `arr` that you are referring to inside the `SetMatrix`?

Comment: Try replacing `++i ` and `++j` with `i++` and `j++`

Comment: class Spreadsheet
    {
       
        private static int n, m;
        private string[,] arr = new string[n, m];
      
        public string[,] SetTable(){}

Comment: @ВладимирНагорный, still not all info. How are `n` and `m` initialized? I expected to see them passed either to constructor or to the method, but seems that neither is the case

Comment: @ВладимирНагорный, also you are quite obviously posting not real code. Class is called Matrix or Spreadsheet? And method, is it SetTable or SetMatrix? You will make everyone's live a lot easier by posting complete code that causes the issue.

Comment: Improved formatting, removed unnecessary closing brace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting your arr array in constructor. Your arr array is always 0 row and 0 column by using the default n and m values. That's why indexOutOfRange is coming.

You can fix this by using a constructor like this-

```
public Matrix(int _n, int _m)
{
    n = _n;
    m = _m;
    arr = new string[n,m];
}
```

Comment: private static int n, m; 
private string[,] arr = new string[n, m];

Comment: please post the complete class. It would be really helpful to see how you initialized your private arr array.